# How do I annotate this function for Flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have this JS function in a file where I use Flow ( https://github.com/facebook/flow )

```
// @flow
static promiseWrapper(fn, ...args) {
  return new Promise(
    async function(resolve, reject) {
      try {
        await fn(...args);
        resolve();
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    }
  )
}
```

How would I go about annotating this?

Comment: That is really not how you use async functions. With this logic, `promiseWrapper` would be the async function, and you'd just do `static async promiseWrapper(fn, ...args){ await fn(...args); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed on the [github project issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1860#issuecomment-222282506), this would be my proposed solution:

```
class Foo {
  // We are using generics <U, T> to define the input type / output type (may be the same... I don't know the use-cases)
  static promiseWrapper<U, T>(fn: (...args: Array<U>) => Promise<T>, ...args: Array<U>): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        // I felt like handling the return value of this await function
        const ret = await fn(...args);
        resolve(ret);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  }
}


// Most of the type inference comes from this function
function fun(...args: Array<number>): Promise<string> {
  const ret = args.reduce((result, num) => (result + num), 0);
  return Promise.resolve(ret.toString());
}

const myProm = Foo.promiseWrapper(fun, 1, 2, 3);

// Here, total should be inferred as string, since our `fun` function returns a Promise<string>
// Generic function definition <T> picks this up correctly :-)
myProm.then((total) => {
  // $ExpectError : total should be inferred as string, hence it should fail on numerical addition
  const foo: number = total + 1;

});
```

Comment: I noted above, but wanted to mention here too, this usage of `new Promise` is an antipattern. `promiseWrapper` should be the async function and this should just return the result, not call a `resolve` callback.